# Set of positive bounded numbers in 2 dimensions, excluding zero

Tags: real-numbers

I want to state that a robot needs to be inside a bounded area. I would like to have a nice short expression like the one below:

$$x \in \mathbb{R}_+^2$$

But what I actually mean is the following:

$$ x_1 \in (0,x_{lim}] \\
   x_2 \in (0,y_{lim}] $$

Which looks rather bulky, and is not easily generalized to higher dimensions. Is there any compact way of stating this?

Comment: What about $(0,x_{lim}]\times (0,y_{lim}]$?

Comment: @5xum that's exactly the kind of expression I was looking for, thank you! Should have thought of it myself.

Comment: Always happy to help:)